# Did the original snake oil work?

Tags: history, alternative-medicine

"Snake oil" is a common name for a fake or over-hyped product. As defined by [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snake%20oil):

> comes from the 19th-century American practice of selling cure-all
>   elixirs in traveling medicine shows. Snake oil salesmen would falsely
>   claim that the potions would cure any ailments. now-a-days it refers
>   to fake products.

But according to "[How Snake Oil Got a Bad Rap](http://www.collectorsweekly.com/articles/how-snake-oil-got-a-bad-rap/)" (*Collectors Weekly*):

> The original snake oil actually worked. Save this one for the
>   next cocktail party; it will blow your friends’ minds.
>
> In the 1860s, Chinese laborers immigrated to the United States to work
>   on the Transcontinental Railroad. At night, they would rub their sore,
>   tired muscles with ointment made from Chinese water snake (Enhydris
>   chinensis), an ancient Chinese remedy they shared with their American
>   co-workers.

and it was all those later salesmen that gave it a bad name.

Although the article contains an explanation and references -- including an [article in *Scientific American*](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=snake-oil-salesmen-knew-something) --  to make this point, are these reasonable?  It seems reasonable to be skeptical of claims that involve old dates, practices of far off cultures, etc...

Comment: General questions are off topic here.  I massively edited this general question to make it into a question that challenges a notable claim.  I note that if the OP wants, they can roll it back and/or edit further by clicking the "edit" link under their post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to NPR's [A History Of 'Snake Oil Salesmen'](http://www.npr.org/blogs/codeswitch/2013/08/26/215761377/a-history-of-snake-oil-salesmen):

> Made from the oil of the Chinese water snake, which is rich in the
> omega-3 acids that help reduce inflammation, snake oil in its original
> form really was effective, especially when used to treat arthritis and
> bursitis. The workers would rub the oil, used for centuries in China,
> on their joints after a long hard day at work. The story goes that the
> Chinese workers began sharing the oil with some American counterparts,
> who marveled at the effects...
>
> ...from psychiatrist and researcher Richard Kunin revealed that the Chinese oil contained
> almost triple the amount of a vital acid as did rattlesnake oil.

So the question now becomes does omega-3 acid help reduce inflammation? According to the [University of Maryland Medical Center](http://umm.edu/health/medical/altmed/supplement/omega3-fatty-acids):

> Research shows that omega-3 fatty acids reduce inflammation and may
> help lower risk of chronic diseases such as heart disease, cancer, and
> arthritis.

And Web MD's [Omega-3 Fact Sheet](http://www.webmd.com/healthy-aging/omega-3-fatty-acids-fact-sheet):

> There are many health benefits of omega-3 fatty acids. Research shows
> strong evidence that the omega-3s EPA and DHA can help lower
> triglycerides and blood pressure. And there are studies showing that
> omega-3 fatty acids may help with other conditions, including
> rheumatoid arthritis, depression, and many more.

So it would seem that original snake oil was helpful. However the term became derogatory after it was found that a major snake oil salesman's oil contained no snake products. [A History Of 'Snake Oil Salesmen'](http://www.npr.org/blogs/codeswitch/2013/08/26/215761377/a-history-of-snake-oil-salesmen)

> Stanley's Snake Oil didn't contain any snake oil at all. The Pure Food
> and Drug Act of 1906 sought to clamp down on the sale of patent
> medicines and it was that legislation that led to Stanley's undoing.
> After seizing a shipment of Stanley's Snake Oil in 1917, federal
> investigators found that it primarily contained mineral oil, a fatty
> oil believed to be beef fat, red pepper and turpentine. That's right —
> Stanley's signature product did not contain a drop of actual snake
> oil, and hundreds of consumers discovered they had been had.
>
> It was probably around then that snake oil became symbolic of fraud.

Comment: Wait, so rubbing an omega-3-rich cream into joints will ease arthritis symptoms? Surely if that was true, it'd be a popular, prescribed practice by people with arthritis? Is it? And do bodybuilders use it as a post-workout thing?

Comment: Is this demonstrated to work as a topical treatment or while taking it orally?

Comment: @user568458 I'm not sure about the rubbing part vs. taken orally for Omega-3 fatty acids, that came from the NPR quote, but apparently it does reduce inflammation. http://umm.edu/health/medical/altmed/supplement/omega3-fatty-acids